# Can't find variable: SMFImageCode

Tags: smartface.io

I read this documentation 
https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/codereader/
then I used this code to generate new code

```
var myImage = new SMF.UI.Image({
        top : "45%",
        left : "10%",
        height : "30%",
        width : "80%"
    });
Pages.Page1.add(myImage);


var myCodeGenerate = new SMF.UI.TextButton({
        top : "30%",
        left : "10%",
        height : "8%",
        width : "80%",
        text : "Generate New Code",
        onPressed : function () {
            var codePath = SMFImageCode.generateCode("Landroid/content/Context;", "content to be into code", "QR_CODE", 500, 500, function (e) {
                    alert(e.message);
                });
            myImage.image = codePath;
        }
    });

Pages.Page1.add(myCodeGenerate);
```

After executing the code I got the following error:

Can't find variable: SMFImageCode

I am using Smarface App Studio 4.5.0

Comment: Did you try it on emulator or publish?

Comment: I tried both, but why should I try publish?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error because I was publishing using x86 :(
When I publish using ARM it works.

Comment: Ok, also emulator doesn't support plugins.You should try plugins on publish.